# How can a python project containing native bindings be distributed via PyPi

Tags: python, packaging, setuptools, pypi

My python project contains some C/C++ bindings with some python code and I want to distribute it through PyPi. If I create a source archive with `python setup.py sdist` and upload it to PyPi, my understanding is it will contain only the source files. How will the native bindings be compiled to match the platform (win/osx/linux) of the user who tries to install my package with "pip install ".

Answer (score 0):

By default it will use the default compiler available on the system. If you want to change that, take a look at these [docs](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#saveopts-save-used-options-to-a-configuration-file) about saveopts.